# How does the expression -2[array] work?

Tags: c++, c

I ran into this beauty, but I can't really understand it!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int array[] = {10, 20, 30};
  cout << -2[array];

  return 0;
}
```

It prints `-30`.
Thank you in advance

Edit: Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542) because of the "-" sign.

Comment: array[2] is the same as 2[array]

Comment: I remember there was a duplicate I've seen for this question. Unfortunately it's not on my favorites list.

Comment: This must have thousands of duplicates!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, i believe, it is different because of the '-'.

Comment: @SergeyA Some question of operator precedence?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, simply because you've comented saying that it was duplicate, I am trying to explain why I believe it is not.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, tried doing so.

Comment: @RobK In which way that's _evil_? Mind to explain more?

Comment: Writing `-2[array]` is what's evil. It's ugly and appears to do something other than what it does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is funny and simple. `-array[2]` is the same as `-*(array + 2)`, which is the same as `-*(2 + array)` which is the same as `-2[array]`, which is -30.

There is already a duplicate for general case of using square brackets with arrays ([With arrays, why is it the case that a[5] == 5[a]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a)), but the quirk here is the **unary `-` operator** in front.

It might seem intuitive to assume that the actual array index would be `-2`, like `array[-2]`.

But this is not happening due to operator precedence rules:

- `operator []` has higher precedence than unary `-`, and as such is applied first.

I've shown the tranformation with 'conventional' array subscription to make this more intuitive

- as we do not negate the array before subscripting it, we do not negate 2 the same way.

Comment: Funny thing is, I understand all the equivalent versions that you mentioned. I just don't "see" why this works. Thank you both!

Comment: Oh.. and by the way, thank you for the link to the related question.